# Getting CORS Error while Integrating FedEx with React Js

Tags: reactjs, fedex, carrier

While working on FedEx integration with React, we are able to get authorization key using Google extension but unable to work on other APIs. All the APIs are perfectly working in postman but not while integration. Tried checking rates and transit times but getting CORS error. I have included the code and error screenshot.Could you please help?

```js
let body = JSON.stringify({
  "accountNumber": {
    "value": "XXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "requestedShipment": {
    "shipper": {
      "address": {
        "postalCode": 75063,
        "countryCode": "US"
      }
    },
    "recipient": {
      "address": {
        "postalCode": "L0J 0A0",
        "countryCode": "CA"
      }
    },
    "pickupType": "DROPOFF_AT_FEDEX_LOCATION",
    "serviceType": "FEDEX_GROUND",
    "rateRequestType": [
      "LIST",
      "ACCOUNT"
    ],
    "customsClearanceDetail": {
      "dutiesPayment": {
        "paymentType": "SENDER",
        "payor": {
          "responsibleParty": null
        }
      },
      "commodities": [{
        "description": "Camera",
        "quantity": 1,
        "quantityUnits": "PCS",
        "weight": {
          "units": "KG",
          "value": 20
        },
        "customsValue": {
          "amount": 100,
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      }]
    },
    "requestedPackageLineItems": [{
      "weight": {
        "units": "KG",
        "value": 20
      }
    }]
  }
});
axios.post("https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/rate/v1/rates/quotes", body, {
  headers : {
  "Accept": "*/*",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "authorization": `Bearer XXX`,
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
}
}).then(res => console.log(res.data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image: CORS Error]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Cors error cannot be solved from front end , cause its a browser error. so You have to create proxy server to solve this
create an API in backend and send request from server to fedex.